# location of properties file in spring mvc project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to inject values of a properties file into a controller in a spring mvc project. I am using spring version 5.0.4.
Below is the definition of my servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="mu.mra" />


    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <util:properties id="countryOptions" location="classpath: countries.properties" />

</beans>
```

the properties file is located in the src/main/resources folder. But unfortunately I am getting the error below

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'studentController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'countryOptions'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException:
>   Expression parsing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1021E:
>   A problem occurred whilst attempting to access the property
>   'countryOptions': 'Error creating bean with name 'countryOptions':
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [
>   countries.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist'

I am not too sure about the location of the properties file. Should it be in the WEB-INF folder? I would like some explanation as well on this if possible.

Thanks,
Ashley

Comment: Check the name... Check it really carefully.... Especially the whitespace between `classpath:` and `countries.properties`.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the properties files do exist in the src/main/resources
you can access them as following

```
<util:properties id="countryOptions" location="classpath:countries.properties" />
```

Or using the annotations

```
@Value( "${property.needed}" )
private String property;
```